# c# DatagridView Control (VirtualMode) and Threading

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a weird issue with the DataGridView control in virtual mode and threading. I use a Cache class to stored 2 pages of data. When I scroll down and I have to load a new page in cache, there is a little delay before data is display (it's ok). But, instead of having
the next row displayed(199th,200th,201th), the control skip many rows (CellValueNeeded). By example, I cached 1 to 200 rows, when I scrolling at 199, I'm loading a page to 200 à 299. However, in the datagrid it's display the row 320.. instead of 300. (I kept the mouse button pressed 2-3 secondes, before releasing it). I notice I have the problem only when I load the cache in a particular thread. Does anyone have a idea how I can fix this?

```
    private void datagridView_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
    {           
        e.Value = m_rfiCache.RetrieveElement(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);            
    }        
    ....

    public DataTable SupplyPageOfData(int lowerPageBoundary, int rowsPerPage)
    {
        e : " + lowerPageBoundary);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        if (m_useThreading) //THIS DOESN'T WORK WELL
        {                 
            Thread MulThread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                dt = this.LoadData(lowerPageBoundary, rowsPerPage);
            });   

            MulThread.Start();

            MulThread.Join();
        }
        else //OK.
        {
            dt = this.LoadData(lowerPageBoundary, rowsPerPage);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

P.S. : This is only a snippet, I used an external API to extract data from ODB. This API used thread to load data.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have a idea or I can fix this?

You can load the data in a background thread, but you can't add it to your main DataTable in the background thread itself.

One potential approach would be to load the data as you're doing, but into a separate DataTable.  You could then, on the UI thread, call [DataSet.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.merge.aspx) to merge this data in with your bound data correctly (which will be reasonable fast).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. When the tread is processing and the scroll down button is pressed, my event for scrolling aren't sent to the datagrid unless my thread is finished. So I received a bunch of calls for drawing cells and the index was wrong. To avoid this, I removed the vs scrollbar from the datagridview and added a VSscrollbar control. When I'm loading data in my thread, I set to false the enable property on my scrollbar. When the thread is completed, I enable the scrollbar. Is not the BEST solution, but at least, there is now row skipped.

Note : Virtual Mode works very well if you don't load your data in a separate thread.